How to remove expired elements from ehcache without deserialization
I have a background job that removes expired elements from Ehcache by invoking the method ehcache.getQuiet(key). However, the getQuiet(key) method internally deserializes the cached object, which leads to time and memory consumption.
Is there a way to remove expired elements without deserializing the object?

How did you configure the expiry policy (https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.10/expiry.html)?

Two questions: 1) which version are you using? Since you are using getQuiet, I suppose is a 2.x, just to understand where to look. 2) You need to remove objects from the cache because they are invalidated somewhere in the application? Because as explained, expired elemets are internally managed by EhCache. Since you already get them by key, have you tried the remove(key) or the removeQuiet(key) methods? Try to take a look to javadoc link.

To eliminate expired elements from Ehcache without deserializing them, you can utilize Ehcache's native expiration mechanism and configurations to automatically manage the expired items. If you’re using this way, you avoid the need to manually check and remove each element using methods that deserialize the object's. That is the way to cache listener events
import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;
import net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache;
import net.sf.ehcache.Element;
import net.sf.ehcache.event.CacheEventListenerAdapter;

CacheManager manager = CacheManager.getInstance();
Ehcache myCache = manager.getCache("myCache");

myCache.getCacheEventNotificationService().registerListener(new CacheEventListenerAdapter() {
 @Override
 public void notifyElementExpired(Ehcache cacheInstance, Element expiredElement) {
     // Handle expiration, element is already removed from cache
     System.out.println("Expired element: " + expiredElement.getObjectKey());
 }
});

